# How to integrate a chat application with other service like GTalk or Yahoo?

Tags: php, chat

I have created a chat application using PHP, but it works only into my site(like the user need come to my site and chat..), i want that user can chat with me through any chat server like Gtalk,yahoo, or MSN. How can it be done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

http://www.meebo.com/websites/

Or if you really want to code yet another chat room http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/ will let you talk to jabber servers i.e Google talk

Comment: hey thank you, @Ciaran Rooney, one more question do we need any special server to create a chat room application using XMPP? like we heve mailservers to send mails..or the normal web server will do..